# Exit from SSH using a sh script

Tags: bash, esxi

I have a RHEL box (bash) and I have SSH'd to an ESXi (sh) from it.

Now on ESXi I have created a simple script

```
#!/bin/sh
echo hello
exit
```

This only exits the script. I want to exit the script + exit the ESXi shell and return to my original RHEL bash.

Thanks much.

Comment: If you run the script with `source`, then when the script ends the login session will also end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the shebang ie do

```
echo hello && exit
```

save it as `script` and then source the `script` like

```
. script
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only SSHing in for the purpose of running this command, then instead you could just have the ssh run the command for you:

```
[RHEL]$ ssh user@ESXi '/tmp/myscript.sh'
```

...and if you needed to interact with the script, or watch it's output, add the `-t` switch:

```
[RHEL]$ ssh -t user@ESXi '/tmp/mysctipt.sh'
```

Comment: The op says ` I have SSH'd to an ESXi (sh)` but this too is a feasible method. :)

Comment: I clarified my opening statement to clear that up...thanks!